# White screen after Ubuntu suspends on iMac

Tags: graphics, suspend, mac, white-screen

I have an iMac running Ubuntu 16.04 not dual booted with MacOSX removed. Processor is an: Intel Core2 Duo CPU P7350 @ 2.00GHz x 2, Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on NVAC, OS type: 64-bit

When I wake it from sleep the screen goes white and I have to click all over the screen to reveal applications and everything else is just white. What should I do?

Cheers Ethan